# Getting "c.instantiate {}" returned as object when referencing a service

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I created a geo location service:

```
angular.module('App')
.service('Geo', ['$http', ($http) ->
  apiUrl = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'

  getData = ->
    $http.get(apiUrl)
      .success((data)->
        console.log data
      )
])
```

Then I include it as a service in my controller:

```
@App.controller 'MyController', ['Geo', (geo)->
  geo.getData()
]
```

I get an error:

> Object [Object object] has no method 'getData'

Inspecting geo gives me `"c.instantiate {}"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: im not familiar with cofeescript but where is your return statement inside service  ??

Comment: Yeah I think if you give the javascript instead of the coffee script you'll get more help

Comment: Yea sorry guys, changed the tag to coffeescript. It returns the last thing by default.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for the service I had to change getData to this.getData to get it to work.

Comment: `getData = -> ...` simply declares a local variable, `getData` and assigns it a function as a value. If you want `getData` to be an object property you have to say so with `@getData = ...` (which is equivalent to `this.getData = ...`).